# How to increment date in datetime in Python list by one day?

Tags: python, date, datetime

There is a list of dates:

```py
date_list = ['2019-09-11 14:50:10.326806' , '2019-09-11 14:50:10.326806', '2019-09-11 14:50:10.326806']
```

type = datetime.datetime

I need to increase only day by 1, from 2019-09-11 to 2019-09-12, but it should also changes in the future without problems. (no 32 september for example)

I've tried like this

```py
for i in start_dates: 
    date += dt.timedelta(days=1)
    print(date) 

# But it results in:

2019-09-12 14:50:10.326806
2019-09-13 14:50:10.326806
2019-09-14 14:50:10.326806
```

Comment: If you are iterating over a list you should be adding `timedelta` to the variable in the list (`i`), not `date` which is not defined in your code snippet but I assume it's just the first element.

Comment: is `start_dates` the same as `date_list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your approach you should be updating the iterable, not sure what `date` is there. Here's one approach using a list comprehension and assuming a list of strings (otherwise no need for `datetime.strptime`):

```
td = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
l = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') + td for i in date_list]
```

---

```
print(l)

[datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 12, 14, 50, 10, 326806),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 12, 14, 50, 10, 326806),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 12, 14, 50, 10, 326806)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over `i`, but printing and changing `date` (which is apparently a local variable outside of the shown scope).

Solution:

```
for date in start_dates:
    date += dt.timedelta(days=1)
    print(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is beeing done 3 times. This happens because `date_list` haves 3 indexes. Also, you have `i` on the loop but you change only the `date`.

**Possible solution:**

```
for date in date_list:            // for each indexes
    date += dt.timedelta(days=1)  // change current index
    print(date)                   // print current index
```